# VS 2017 - USQL - Parse pipe delimited file

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm trying to parse (convert single column with pipes to multiple string columns AND also assign variable types to each of the resulting columns) a pipe-delimited file in USQL / Azure using VS 2017.

The file has been loaded into a folder already but when I look at it, it's just a single string column with pipes visible in the data.

```
Column_0
fields1|field2|field3
123|456|abc
```

I have a couple scripts I'm trying to copy / tweak but I'm getting a bunch of errors that aren't very informative.

My script looks like this:

```
@input = 
    EXTRACT [Column_0] string
    FROM "adl://~/raw/file1.txt"
    USING Extractors.Tsv(skipFirstNRows:1, quoting: false, silent: true);

@res1 =
    SELECT 
                [field1] string,
                [field2] string,
                [field3] string
    FROM @input;

OUTPUT @res1   
    TO "adl://~/processed/file1.csv"    
    USING Outputters.Csv(quoting: false);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please send me the errors you are getting so we can improve them? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Text Extractor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt764098.aspx), and specify "|" as delimiter.

```
@data = 
    EXTRACT
        field1 string,
        field2 string,
        field3 string
    FROM "/input1.txt"
    USING Extractors.Text(skipFirstNRows:1, quoting: false, silent: true, delimiter: '|');


OUTPUT @data
    TO "/output1.csv"    
    USING Outputters.Csv(quoting: false);
```